# What's an easy way to update the value of a single column in a one row table with SQLite's sqlite-net-pcl library?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I'm using the SQLite's sqlite-net-pcl library and here is the table I have. What I would like to know is, how can I update the value to 2 after the table is created?

```
db2.CreateTable<Schema>();
db2.Insert(new Schema() { SchemaGuid = new Guid().ToString(), Version = 1 });
public class Schema
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string SchemaGuid   { get; set; }
    public int    Version      { get; set; }
}
var version = RunQuery<int>($"SELECT Version FROM Schema").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the 'UpdateAsync' to update the version value with the same `PrimaryKey`.

Insert the record:

```
db2.InsertAsync(new Schema() { ID = 1, SchemaGuid = new Guid().ToString(), Version = 0 });
```

**Update:**

```
db2.UpdateAsync(new Schema() { ID = 1, SchemaGuid = new Guid().ToString(), Version = 2 });
```

And you could check all the records in the list with the code below:

```
db2.Table<Schema>().ToListAsync();
```

For mroe details, you could refer to the MS document.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows